# Iterate over commits by date

Tags: macos, git, shell

I'm trying to write a script do some code coverage stats on a git repository. But I only want to sample the data about once every 6 months. Is there a way to write a script that does something like this:

psuedocode:

```
foreach (commit in all-commits)
    if(commit.date % 6months == 0)
        commit.checkout
        <run my unit test coverage here>
```

Answer (score 1):

git support this:

```
 git log --since=2.weeks.ago --until=2.days.ago
```